# unmet dependencies for mate-desktop

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, remote-desktop, rdp

I need to RDP from my Windows machine into my ubuntu machine.

I'm using this tutorial to do that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1ay7toiJ6k

It recommends to go to run the following from wiki.mate-desktop.org:
[image]

and now we install it:
[image]

finally, we get this:
[image]

here's my version of ubuntu:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How can I RDP into linux from my windows machine?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a program called XRDP. This is the only way I've found to make RDP connections into a linux box. You shouldn't need to install MATE at all.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

After you install this program you should be able to RDP into your linux machine.

I would personally suggest connecting to your linux box in a different way if possible- RDP connections into linux haven't really worked to well for me before, but you should definitely give this a shot.

**EDIT:** If you wish to continue following the youtube tutorial and want to use the MATE desktop, try this.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

You can thank nDCasT in the youtube comments if this works for you. Though if your purpose is to just to connect to your machine using RDP, you shouldn't really need this step at all.

Comment: thhank you so much. how else besides RDP do you recommend to connect to a linux machine from windows within the same network AND be able to view the linux gui (unlike in plain ssh)

Comment: VNC is the option that has always worked well for me. You're probably not going to find a remote solution that's going to work as well as windows to windows RDP.

You can try remotex windows. http://www.cse.yorku.ca/tdb/_doc.php/userg/login/x11-from-home.html This will give you access to certain programs on your system and run them in a 'native' windows format (I.E. in windows with windows decorations), it really is one of the cooler features of Xorg. You should try em both out in your free time, though VNC is definitely the easier if laggier option :)